# Does sails.js support database views?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I would like to migrate my application to sails.js. But, I use database views on my PostgreSQL database for some functions.

I try to make a model for this view. But, it causes an ORM error when I perform `sails lift`.

```
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: error: relation "homeview" already exists
at Connection.parseE (/home/onlinemad/git/appname2/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:561:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (/home/onlinemad/git/appname2/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:390:17)
at null.<anonymous> (/home/onlinemad/git/appname2/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:92:20)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
```

Does sails.js support database views, and if so do they require special configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a database view with your Sails app by setting the `migrate` property to `safe` in the model that uses the view:

```
module.exports = {
   migrate: 'safe',
   attributes: {
      ...
   }
}
```

This will restrict Sails from performing migrations on the view, meaning that if you add new attributes to the model, they will *not* be automagically added to the database view.  You'll have to keep your Sails model and your database view in sync manually.

Comment: It's good workaround to support database view. It would be better, if Sails.js can support database view officially.

Comment: Might be a bit late to the party, but I wrote a blog post about this which includes a sample project at http://uhndev.github.io/2015/08/04/using-database-views-with-sailsjs/